# Why do I get a heap error when using iter_swap this way?

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

Please view my code for Reverse String on LeetCode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
    public:
        void printVector(vector<char>& s){
            for(auto i: s){
                cout << i << ", ";
            }
        }
        
        void reverseString(vector<char>& s) {
            
            for(int pos = 0; pos <= s.size()/2; pos++){
                iter_swap(s.begin() + pos - 1, s.end() - pos);
            }
            printVector(s);
        }
};

// test 

int main()
{
    Solution *sol = new Solution;
    vector<char> c1{'a', 'd', 'r', 'g', 'z', 'p'};
    sol->reverseString(c1);
    delete sol;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try running this code on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler, it works perfectly. However, when I run class Solution on LeetCode, it gives me:

`==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6020000000cf at pc 0x000000344899 bp 0x7fff6d1a45d0 sp 0x7fff6d1a45c8`

After looking online, I still don't really understand why I am getting a heap overflow error specifically for my kind of code iteration. Help?!

Comment: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain" - Scotty, Star Trek III. None of the shown fancy iterator stuff is necessary, there is no reason for it, whatsoever. Reversing a string can be accomplished via much more straightforward means, coming nowhere near `std::iter_swap`. The resulting, complicated math and logic is wrong, and results in several off-by-1s resulting in memory corruption and undefined behavior.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your input. I will try another method then.

Comment: You see, unfortunately, sites like LeetCode are bunch of useless collections of puzzles and nothing more. There's nothing there that actually teaches proper algorithms and logic, and the correct way to use containers and iterators. The only way to improve one's C++ skills, is by a methodical, coordinated study regiment from a C++ textbook, and not Leetcode, or Hackerrank, or any of other similar junksites. If you were to, instead, studied with a textbook, you would learned that this is, simply: `auto b=s.begin(); auto e=s.end(); while (b < e) { --e; std::swap(*b, *e); ++b; }` that's it.

Comment: Thank you so much. After evaluating your code, that is much straightforward. Honestly I am using this website because of interview preparation, yet it's true, I think I should switch to an actual algorithms based textbook. Thanks again.

Comment: If someone learns, studies, knows, and understands algorithms, they can solve any and every puzzle on Leetcode/Hackerrank/GeeksForGeeks/et.al., now and forever. The puzzles that are there now, and any new ones that get added in the future. If someone only memorizes solutions to puzzles on Leetcode/HackerRank/GeeksforGeeks/et.al, they will know how to solve only the ones that they managed to memorize, and not forget, and not any others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for(int pos = 0; pos <= s.size()/2; pos++){
        iter_swap(s.begin() + pos - 1, s.end() - pos);
```

Here, when `pos = 0`, this accesses out of range and thus causes undefined behavior: `s.begin() + pos - 1`.

Comment: The code only worked when I added -1 in the GDB. I then get this error on LeetCode: Line 58: Char 12: runtime error: index -66 out of bounds for type 'std::string [256]' (_Serializer_.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior _Serializer_.cpp:67:12`

Comment: You have two off-by-one errors.  Both `s.begin() + 0 - 1` and `s.end() - 0` trigger Undefined Behavior if dereferenced.  You are trying to move memory that isn't yours.

Comment: Thanks @DrewDormann. I never heard of an off-by-one error before, so I'll look into that.